# How can I get the count of keys in redis?

Tags: redis

I can get some keys with this command:

```
keys *_products_*
```

However that command returns all the keys, where I just need the count of those. How can I get It?

Answer (score 13):

DBSIZE
Return the number of keys in the database

[image]

http://redis.io/commands/dbsize

Answer (score 11):

You can use [DBSIZE](http://redis.io/commands/dbsize) or [INFO KEYSPACE](http://redis.io/commands/info)

But if you want all the keys with a certain pattern in the name you need to use [KEYS](http://redis.io/commands/keys) or [SCAN](http://redis.io/commands/scan) And you need to pay attention to `KEYS`, running it in production can affect the performance so it should be used with caution.

Answer (score 3):

Both (evil) `KEYS` and the much preferred `SCAN` do not return counts, only key names. You could wrap them in a Lua script to just return the count.

However.

Doing `KEYS` (or `SCAN`) in real time is very expensive in terms of performance - it means that you're iterating over the entire keyspace. What you want to do is keep the result ready beforehand, and then just fetch it. Usually in such cases, you'd use a Redis Set in which you'd store each relevant key name - SADD to it whenever you create a key that matches the patter `*products*` and delete from it whenever a key is removed.

But.

Since you're only interesting in a count, you can replace that Set with a simple counter.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command line:

```
redis-cli --scan --pattern '*_products_*' | wc -l
```