# Redis wildcard search and returning hash values (%word)

Tags: redis

I use Redis 3.0.6

I'm trying to create an autocomplete feature using Redis. I keep three things in a hash, a band name, its rank and the year it was founded.

I want to do a wildcard search in order to get the band names that start with a certain letter(s) and their additional features, like their ranks and years.

How can I do that? Is it possible to do at once or do I need a subquery to get their properties?

```
HMSET 3doorsdown rank 7 year 2003
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> HMSET adele rank 1 year 2005
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> HMSET almora rank 3 year 1995
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> HMSET amiina rank 2 year 2009
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> HMSET anathema rank 4 year 1990
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> HMSET birdy rank 6 year 2012
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> HMSET blink182 rank 5 year 1999
OK
```

`SCAN 0 match a* COUNT 1000` returns all records that start with a, but not their ranks and years.

```
1) "0"
2) 1) "adele"
   2) "almora"
   3) "anathema"
   4) "amiina"
127.0.0.1:6379>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33625191/3210431

I didn't use KEYS since it's expensive, but it also has been said that SCAN is expensive (above), too.

What should I do? Do I need to keep the names in a SET, do a match via SCAN AND if there's a match, I should look up those records in HASHES individually by their names, like below?

1-) Look for band names that start with a in a SET

2-) 4 records returned

3-) Get their features via HGETALL in HASHES

---

EDIT : I have another idea. I keep names in a SET, use ZRANGEBYLEX and do another query in HASH to get the properties, but I don't know which one is the right way to do.

Comment: The approach in your edit is the way to do it since the introduction of lexicographical ranges in 2.8.

Comment: @ItamarHaber thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antirez has written an [article about autocomplete](http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/autocomplete-with-redis.html) you might find useful and can get some ideas from, but in essence:

Using SCAN will be expensive and see you iterating over your whole key set, so a sorted set will be the better way to go. You can utilize lexicographic sorting on the set to do most of the heavy lifting for you.  The downside is you're trading memory for speed.  Once you have the matching keys you can do a HGETALL to fetch the matching records.  If you're worried about roundtrip times you can combine this all into a single lua script (I would recommend this).

Comment: I actually found this article this morning but didn't read since it was written in 2010. That was all I need. To sum up, I still need to keep a hash "database" and a "sorted set" database, right? If a match occurs, I will query the hash database with exact name without a wildcard (since I will have it returned from sorted set) to show the records. Thank you, by the way. It was really helpful.

Comment: That's exactly what you'd do - your hash lookups now become an O(1) operation.  Glad it helped